# Use a declared variable in a SELECT statement

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

I'm using Oracle 10g and need to use a variable in a where clause of a **SELECT**; eg.

```
DECLARE
v_blah NUMBER;
BEGIN

v_blah := 13;

SELECT * FROM PEOPLE p WHERE p.LuckyNumber = v_blah;

END;
```

but am getting an error saying

> PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

It seems to work fine in a DELETE or INSERT statement, so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work here.

Comment: I'm confsed by that ... that should work :(

Comment: Welcome to Oracle. It's not SQL Server ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
DECLARE
  v_blah NUMBER := 13;
  v_people_rec PEOPLE%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO v_people_rec FROM PEOPLE p WHERE p.LuckyNumber = v_blah;
END;
```

The [select statement in PL/SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm) requires a place where store the query result. In this example the place is `v_people_rec` variable.

The example above expects *exactly one row* to be returned. In other cases it will throw exceptions `NO_DATA_FOUND` or `TOO_MANY_ROWS`.

Answer (score 3):

That isn't anything to do with your parameter, it is because you're executing your code as a procedural block of code so it doesn't allow you to select to nothing.

What do you want to do with the result of the query?  Display it to the screen?  If so, select it to a cursor, iterate through and use dbms_output.

Comment: I want to return the row.  This would be part of a larger, insert, then return the inserted row type of query.

Comment: In that case you'll need to select the results into a cursor.