# How to use single quote twice in constructing select statement

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, dynamic-sql

I am constructing Dynamic Sql, Dont understand how to  use single quote in the select statement, which contains some variables

For E.g.

```
SELECT ABC.NEXTVAL,'||val_name||' Vname,'||ta_tab||' Tname,'||', Accnt_id, rowid from emp;
```

Where val_name and ta_tab are NOT column of the table Emp, but those are variables  calculated in block, and  I require them to Insert into another table directly.

How to solve This, I tried using 'Double-quotes' but it doesnt work and variable values are not printed ( it considered as string )

Comment: This is not a Duplicate question, I already gone through that question. If I use '' like this below is the out put.                                                                                          SELECT ABC.NEXTVAL,'||val_name||' Vname,'||ta_tab||' Tname,'||',Accnt_id, rowid from emp;

Comment: googled `plsql using variable in select statements` and got this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861012/use-a-declared-variable-in-a-select-statement) . Let us know if this doesn't satisfy your needs.

Comment: Why are you trying to use dynamic SQL for this; and what are you doing with the returned data? Is this supposed to be part of an `insert into ... select ...` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned, there is no need of **dynamic SQL** here.

However, if  you just want to know how to use single-quotes for learning purpose, here is an example,

```
SQL> SET serveroutput ON
SQL> DECLARE
  2    val_name VARCHAR2(10);
  3    ta_tab   VARCHAR2(10);
  4    v_str    VARCHAR2(100);
  5    A        VARCHAR2(10);
  6    b        VARCHAR2(10);
  7    c        VARCHAR2(10);
  8    d        NUMBER;
  9  BEGIN
 10    val_name := 'LALIT';
 11    ta_tab   := 'TEST';
 12    v_str    :='SELECT '''||val_name||''', ename,'''||ta_tab||''', sal from emp where empno = 7788';
 13    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_str INTO A,b,c,d;
 14    dbms_output.put_line(a||'-'||b||'-'||c||'-'||d);
 15  END;
 16  /
LALIT-SCOTT-TEST-3000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

There are other things to keep in mind, like using bind variables etc. however, it is out of scope of this topic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use literal quoting:

```
stmt := q'[SELECT ABC.NEXTVAL,'||val_name||' Vname,'||ta_tab||' Tname,'||', Accnt_id, rowid from emp]';
```

Documentation for literals can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#sthref344

Alternatively, you can use three quotes to denote a single quote:

```
stmt := 'SELECT ABC.NEXTVAL,'''||val_name||''' Vname,'''||ta_tab||''' Tname,'''||''', Accnt_id, rowid from emp';
```

The literal quoting mechanism with the Q syntax is more flexible and readable, IMO.

Comment: It is wrong. You are enclosing the variables into the quote literal as well.

Comment: It doesnt work , it gives below issues....... If I use '' like this below is the out put.                                                                                          SELECT ABC.NEXTVAL,'||val_name||' Vname,'||ta_tab||' Tname,'||',Accnt_id, rowid from emp;

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using dynamic sql, why can't you just use the variables directly in the SQL? E.g.:

```
declare
  val_name varchar2(30) := 'fred';
  ta_tab varchar2(30) := 'bob';
begin
  insert into some_table (id, vname, tname, accnt_id, row_id)
  select abc.nextval,
         val_name vname,
         ta_tab tname,
         accnt_id,
         rowid
  from   emp;
end;
/
```

Comment: I have to use Dynamic sql

Comment: @rohansr002 - *why* do you have to use dynamic SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Team, I found the answer. In oracle I have to use ' 3 times

E.g.

stmt := 'SELECT ABC.NEXTVAL,'''||val_name||''' Vname,'''||ta_tab||''' Tname,''||'', Accnt_id, rowid from emp'

Above query worked. Thanks!!!

Comment: I'm still curious as to why you feel like you need to use dynamic sql?

Comment: @rohansr002 Don't post "thanks" as an answer. You can add it as a comment. Upvote and/or accept the answer which solved your problem. Answer section should be used only to post an answer.

Comment: I put in answer section because, I found the correct answer ..!!